# bash race condition using generated output file name

Tags: bash

I am trying to generate output using a randomized file name. "Generating" is simulated with "cat" in this example:

```
cat report.csv > "test_$(openssl rand -base64 102).csv"
```

I often get an error like this:

```
-bash: test_Q6eheRaVfktCTCfWSU/tjRNA1y+6juwlyuo1lEId/7HZTCQIE7/rt+/9MlTI+pjT
9It3l7FtBldMmaqHNWpspwCI5kCpR+s51RA2o9xAZ6BrZ+7UBR5atK9qWdSO/N/X
BAnvDkGm.csv: No such file or directory
```

The probability for this error is higher the higher the number of random characters is, which suggests a race condition. Solving the problem by using a variable for the random characters is obvious and is not what I am asking. Rather, my question is: What are the individual steps that bash performs, and where is the race condition?

I would have thought that bash executes the command as follows:

- Create a pipe to capture the output of openssl rand
- fork/exec openssl rand, passing that file handle as stdout, and wait for the process to finish (and check error status)
- read from the pipe to get the value used in string interpolation, then close the pipe
- perform string interpolation to build the output file name
- open the output file
- fork/exec cat, passing the handle for the output file as stdout
- wait for the process to finish (and check error status), then close the output file

Nothing here suggests a race condition. I could imagine that bash instead runs cat in parallel and opens another pipe to buffer its output before it goes into the output file, but that wouldn't cause a "No such file or directory" either.

As was commented, slashes in the filename are an obvious problem, but the error occurs even without slashes. Setting the number of random bytes to 8 sometimes produces errors like this, without a slash and with the correct number of characters (so no slash was hidden):

```
-bash: test_9od1IhDt5A4=.csv: No such file or directory
```

The following command waits 2 seconds, then runs the command. In exactly those cases where the strange error message appears, it waits 4 seconds instead. Is there some kind of repeat login in bash that does this?

```
cat report.csv > "test_$(sleep 2; openssl rand -base64 9).csv"
```

Confirmed the double execution by echoing to stderr instead of sleeping:

```
cat report.csv > "test_$(echo foo 1>&2; openssl rand -base64 9).csv"
```

Comment: I guess the problem is more related with the slashes (```/```) in the file name than a race condition.

Comment: Why don't you try [```mktemp```](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktemp.3.html) instead?

Comment: I'm still inclined to think the problem is with special characters in the file name.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on macOS (10.14.6 Mojave) with Apple Bash 3.2.57(1) — using size 8 in place of 102.  Sometimes, the name that fails has a slash in it; sometimes it doesn't.  There isn't an obvious rhyme or to why the names without slashes fails (I can use copy'n'paste to create the file after the loop fails to do so).  I used a loop like `for i in $(seq 1 100); do cat /dev/null > "test_$(openssl rand -base64 8)"; done`.  I also tried variants capturing the file name and echoing it and the value of `$i`, but none of it made much sense.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error using something that generates "safer" names? Maybe something like ```openssl rand -base64 -hex 102```.

Comment: @accdias — When using only `-hex` (not both `-base64` and `-hex`), then I did not get any failures.

Comment: One thing that puzzles me is that if I create a script to do the job and then run that `bash runit.sh`, the failing names always seem to have a slash.  When I run it directly at the terminal (history is useful), it fails on some names without slashes.  I do not understand this behaviour.

Comment: Because the problem IS with special characters in the file name! :-). I'm pretty sure the fails you get when executing the test you posted is with files with, for example, an equal sign (```=```) in the name, which is pretty common output for base64 strings.

Comment: @accdias: With `-base64 8`, every single name contains an `=` immediately before the `.csv`.  Change it to 9 and the `=` goes away, but the errors don't.  It isn't the plus signs either — I have many files with `+` in the name.  I've also run the error messages through a program that identifies non-printing characters; there's nothing untoward in the output, though.  My `ulimit` gives me 256 files; I'm only doing 100 iterations at a time.

Comment: My bad. 
Because the problem IS with special characters in the file name! :-). I'm pretty sure the fails you get when executing the test you posted is with files with, for example, an slash (```/```) in the name, which is pretty common output for base64 strings.

Comment: I run the same tests here and all the fails I've got where with file names with a slash somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199500/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-accdias).

Comment: Suggestion: don't use `-base64` — do use `-hex` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the point of the question was to understand the problem, not to find a solution ;) I read your chat and it seems tricky; I ran into the problem on the Mac too and I'm beginning to think that it is either a problem with macOS or with the specific bash version pre-installed there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Several things are happening here.

The key part is that an error in the command substitution causes it to be evaluated *twice*. This seems to be a bug in the bash version used by Apple. The changelog at https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES says for version bash-4.3-alpha: "Fixed a bug that could result in double evaluation of command substitutions when they appear in failed redirections." I ran my tests on "GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)", the version pre-installed on macOS.

Steps to reproduce this bug in a simple way:

```
lap47:~/Documents> echo foo > "test_$(echo bar 1>&2; echo 'foo')"
bar
lap47:~/Documents> echo foo > "test_$(echo bar 1>&2; echo 'f/oo')"
bar
bar
-bash: test_f/oo: No such file or directory
lap47:~/Documents>
```

The second important part is that evaluating the command substitution twice invokes openssl rand twice, producing *different* random numbers. The second invocation seems to be used to generate the error message after the redirection failed. This way, the error message does *not* reflect the condition that caused the error.

Finally, the root cause of the failed redirection is indeed a slash in the file name. This failure causes the substitution to be invoked again, producing a different file name which somewhat likely doesn't contain a slash.

Comment: That bug has nothing to do with your original post since you are not doing any kind of redirection there.

Comment: The problem still the fact of some file names having slashes on it and the proof is that the problem disappears when you change the names generated to contain just hex digits, for example.

Comment: The redirection of stdout of "echo" to a file is super obvious here. Also, your chat with Jonathan Leffler shows that the error occurs even without a slash. The chat also reveals that you want your initial statement about the slash being the problem to be accepted at all cost, which is not what SO is for. Finally, the linked bug is very relevant because it causes an incorrect error message to be produced, and is the key part of the answer to my initial question. I do agree however that this answer is not stated in a proper Q&A style, so I will edit it to correct that.